# как удалить элементы из массива

Tags: c++, массивы

Нашел минимальный и максимальный элементы массива, теперь их нужно удалить.
Из идей пока только отсортировать и "обрезать" массив, но хотелось бы знать как еще можно это сделать
upd: массив небольшой и из целых цисел

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: что непонятного? нужно удалить 2 элемента из массива. Хочу знать как можно больше вариантов как это сделать

Comment: Для динамических — https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/realloc, для автоматических — никак, перемещайте в конец и уменьшайте размер фиктивно.

Answer (score 2):

Сортировать не надо. Надо разделить все элементы на подходящие и не подходящие. Не подходящие вытесняются в конец массива, который затем отрезается - [erase–remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) или [erase_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase2) в C++ 20. Для `vector` реализуется так:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a = {9, 8, 7, -100, 6, 5, 4, 100, 3, 2, 1, 0};

    const int min = *min_element(a.begin(), a.end());
    const int max = *max_element(a.begin(), a.end());

    auto extremes = [min, max](int v) { return v == min || v == max; };

    // erase_if(a, extremes), если у вас C++ 20
    a.erase(remove_if(a.begin(), a.end(), extremes), a.end());

    for (int v : a) {
        std::cout << v << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

> ```
> $ g++ -std=c++17 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror temp.cpp && ./a.out
> 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
> ```

Обрезать массив таким образом не получится. Можно запомнить его длину после чистки:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int a[] = {9, 8, 7, -100, 6, 5, 4, 100, 3, 2, 1, 0};

    const int min = *std::min_element(std::begin(a), std::end(a));
    const int max = *std::max_element(std::begin(a), std::end(a));

    auto extremes = [min, max](int v) { return v == min || v == max; };

    const auto garbage = std::remove_if(std::begin(a), std::end(a), extremes);

    for (auto it = std::begin(a); it != garbage; ++it) {
        std::cout << *it << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

> ```
> $ g++ -std=c++17 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror temp.cpp && ./a.out
> 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
> ```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase2. Но я думаю, что ТСу надо именно для массивов, а не для векторов.

Comment: @tocic, спасибо. Поправил оба замечания.